# IP based redirection with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to set up a redirect in Apache using the `.htaccess` file. The redirect would be used to force users into a maintenance page temporary.

> How can I redirect users from http://devsparkle.me and http://www.devsparkle.me to http://www.devsparkle.me/maintenance?

and

> How can I prevent localhost, *127.0.0.1* users from being redirected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !127\.0\.0\.1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?devsparkle\.me$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!maintenance).* /maintenance [L,R]
```

Comment: @ricalou 127.0.0.1 means you are attempted to connect from the webserver itself, if that's not the case, then you need to use the outside facing IP address, the IP address the remote web server sees.